# localization resource not found. partialViews and controllers

Tags: asp.net-core, location, asp.net-core-mvc

I am getting resource not found = true in this line

```
ViewData["MenuItem_AboutUs"] = localizer["MenuItem_AboutUs"];
```

also I am not sure how to use localization on partialviews, I couldn't find any sample.

PartialView

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization

@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer


<a href="#">@Localizer["MenuItem_AboutUs"]</a>
```

STARTUP

```
services.AddMvc(options =>

            {
    options.Filters.Add(typeof(MyAuthorizeAttribute));

})
                    // Add support for finding localized views, based on file name suffix, e.g. Index.fr.cshtml
                    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
                    // Add support for localizing strings in data annotations (e.g. validation messages) via the
                    // IStringLocalizer abstractions.
                    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(); services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("en"),
                new CultureInfo("fr")
            };

// State what the default culture for your application is. This will be used if no specific culture
// can be determined for a given request.
options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-US", uiCulture: "en-US");


// You must explicitly state which cultures your application supports.
// These are the cultures the app supports for formatting numbers, dates, etc.
options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;


 // These are the cultures the app supports for UI strings, i.e. we have localized resources for.
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });
    }
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline. 
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)

{
    loggerFactory.AddFile("Logs/GWP-{Date}.log");


    var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();

    app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);`
```

CONTROLLER

```
namespace Web.Controllers
{
    public class IndexController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly IAppSettings appSettings;
        private readonly IStringLocalizer<IndexController> localizer;
        public IndexController(IAppSettings appSettings, IStringLocalizer<IndexController> localizer) : base(appSettings)
        {
            this.localizer = localizer;
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["MenuItem_AboutUs"] = localizer["MenuItem_AboutUs"];
            return View();
        }
    }
}`
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Just keep consistent directory structure.

By the way, you've configured a `supportedCultures` in your startup class :

```
var supportedCultures = new[]
{
    new CultureInfo("en"),
    new CultureInfo("fr")
};
```

But your `resx` files are :

- _Header.en.resx
- _Header.resx
- _Header.tr.resx

There seems a typo. You should rename the last resource file as `_Header.fr.resx`.

**How to in details**

The default partial view resides in `Views/Shared` folder. You can also create your own partial folder:

```
Views/
    Home/
    Index/
        Index.cshtml
    Shared/
        _HeaderPartial.cshtml
    PartialViews/
        _Header2Partial.cshtml
```

Your directory structure of resource should be

```
Resources/
    Controllers/
        IndexController.fr.resx
    Views/
    Shared/
        _HeaderPartial.fr.resx
    PartialViews/
        _Header2Partial.fr.resx
```

When you want to use the localizer, simply using the namespace and inject a service :

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer

you can use @Localizer[] now
```

**Test Case :**

partial view of `Views/Shared/_HeaderPartial.cshtml`:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer

<header>This is header from partial : @Localizer["hello world"] </header>
```

The `Shared/_HeaderPartial.fr.resx`:

```
|    Name          |     value                                      |
|------------------+------------------------------------------------+
| hello world      |    Bonjour le monde (from `/Shared/` folder)   |
```

The `PartialViews/_Header2Partial.cshtml` :

```
|    Name          |     value                                       |
|------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| hello world      | Bonjour le monde (from `/PartialViews/` folder) |
```

resource files :

[image]

the rendered page :

[image]